# Error when creating custom dashboard using WooCommerce REST API

Tags: php, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am building a custom dashboard seen here:
https://github.com/shahroznawaz/woo-dashboard

I am getting this error:
**Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /Users/helloworld/Desktop/test/index.php:153 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Users/helloworld/Desktop/test/index.php on line 153

I have found another stackoverflow post with the same error which is unresolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64648006/error-in-a-custom-dashboard-using-woocommerce-rest-api)
How Can I adjust my code to prevent the errors?

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;
use Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException;
$woocommerce = new Client(
    'http://localhost:10053/', // Your store URL
    'consumerkeyhere', // Your consumer key
    'secretkeyhere', // Your consumer secret
    [
        'wp_api' => true, // Enable the WP REST API integration
        'version' => 'wc/v2' // WooCommerce WP REST API version
        
    ]
);

//$products = $woocommerce->get('products');


try {

    $results = $woocommerce->get('orders');
    $products = $woocommerce->get('products');
    $customers = $woocommerce->get('customers');
    $result = count($results);
    $customer = count($customers);
    $product = count($products);
    $query = ['date_min' => '2017-10-01', 'date_max' => '2021-10-30'];
    $sales = $woocommerce->get('reports/sales', $query);
    $sale = $sales[0]->total_sales;

    // Last request data.

    $lastRequest = $woocommerce->http->getRequest();
    $lastRequest->getUrl(); // Requested URL (string).
    $lastRequest->getMethod(); // Request method (string).
    $lastRequest->getParameters(); // Request parameters (array).
    $lastRequest->getHeaders(); // Request headers (array).
    $lastRequest->getBody(); // Request body (JSON).

    // Last response data.

    $lastResponse = $woocommerce->http->getResponse();
    $lastResponse->getCode(); // Response code (int).
    $lastResponse->getHeaders(); // Response headers (array).
    $lastResponse->getBody(); // Response body (JSON).
}

catch(HttpClientException $e) {
    $e->getMessage(); // Error message.
    $e->getRequest(); // Last request data.
    $e->getResponse(); // Last response data.
}

if (isset($_POST['btn-update'])) {
    $status = $_POST['bookId'];
    $st = $_POST['ostatus'];

    $woocommerce->put('orders/' . $status, array(
        'status' => $st
    ));
    header('Location: http://localhost:10053/');
}


if (isset($_POST['btn-delete'])) {
    $oid = $_POST['cId'];

    $woocommerce->delete('orders/' . $oid, ['force' => true]);
    header('Location: http://localhost:10053/');
}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <title>Dashboard Template for Bootstrap</title>

</head>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                     <h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1>

                     <div class="row placeholders">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
                                    <p id="large">
                                        <?php echo $result?>
                                    </p>
                                    <hr>
                                    <span class="text-muted">New Orders</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
                                    <p id="large">
                                        <?php echo $customer?>
                                    </p>
                                    <hr>

                                    <span class="text-muted">Customers</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
                                    <p id="large">
                                        <?php echo $product?>
                                    </p>
                                    <hr>
                                    <span class="text-muted">All Products</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
                                    <p id="large">
                                        <?php echo $sale?>
                                    </p>
                                    <hr>
                                    <span class="text-muted">Total Sales</span>
                                </div>
                      </div>
              </div>
      </div>
             <div class="container">
                              <h2 class="sub-header">Orders List</h2>
                                <div class='table-responsive'>
                                    <table id='myTable' class='table table-striped table-bordered'>
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Order #</th>
                                                <th>Customer</th>
                                                <th>Address</th>
                                                <th>Contact</th>
                                                <th>Order Date</th>
                                                <th>Status</th>
                                                <th>Actions</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <?php foreach ($results as $details){

                echo "<tr><td>" . $details["id"]."</td>
                          <td>" . $details["billing"]["first_name"].$details["billing"]["last_name"]."</td>
                          <td>" . $details["shipping"]["address_1"]."</td>
                          <td>" . $details["billing"]["phone"]."</td>
                          <td>" . $details["date_created"]."</td>
                          <td>" . $details["status"]."</td>
                          <td><a class='open-AddBookDialog btn btn-primary' data-target='#myModal' data-id=".$details['id']." data-toggle='modal'>Update</a>
                          <a class='open-deleteDialog btn btn-danger' data-target='#myModal1' data-id=".$details['id']." data-toggle='modal'>Delete</a></td></tr>";
                }
                ?>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
               </div>

                <div class="container">
                                    <h2 class="sub-header">Customers List</h2>
                                    <div class='table-responsive'>
                                        <table id='myTable' class='table table-striped table-bordered'>
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Email</th>
                                                    <th>Name</th>
                                                    <th>Billing Address</th>
                                                    <th>Total Orders</th>
                                                    <th>Total spent</th>
                                                    <th>Avatar</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <?php 
                    foreach($customers as $customer){

                    echo "<tr><td>" . $customer["email"]."</td>
                              <td>" . $customer["first_name"].$customer["last_name"]."</td>
                              <td>" . $customer["billing"]["address_1"]."</td>
                              <td>" . $customer["orders_count"]."</td>
                              <td>" . $customer["total_spent"]."</td>
                              <td><img height='50px' width='50px' src='".$customer["avatar_url"]."'></td></tr>";
                    }

                    ?>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
                                    <h2 class="sub-header">Products List</h2>
                                    <div class='table-responsive'>
                                        <table id='myTable' class='table table-striped table-bordered'>
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>SKU</th>
                                                    <th>Name</th>
                                                    <th>Status</th>
                                                    <th>Price</th>
                                                    <th>Total Sales</th>
                                                    <th>Picture</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <?php 
                    foreach($products as $product){

                    echo "<tr><td>" . $product["sku"]."</td>
                              <td>" . $product["name"]."</td>
                              <td>" . $product["status"]."</td>
                              <td>" . $product["price"]."</td>
                              <td>" . $product["total_sales"]."</td>
                              <td><img height='50px' width='50px' src='".$product["images"][0]["src"]."'></td></tr>";
                    }

                    ?>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
    </div>

  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Update Order Status</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Order ID:</p>
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bookId" id="bookId" value="">

                        <p for="sel1">Select list (select one):</p>
                        <select class="form-control" id="status" name="ostatus">
                            <option>Pending Payment</option>
                            <option>processing</option>
                            <option>On Hold</option>
                            <option>completed</option>
                            <option>Cancelled</option>
                            <option>Refunded</option>
                            <option>Failed</option>
                        </select>

                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block" name="btn-update">Update</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm Order Deletion</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Really you want to delete order?</p>
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cId" id="cId" value="">
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="btn-delete">Delete</button>
                   </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



        <script>
            $(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function() {
                var myBookId = $(this).data('id');
                $(".modal-body #bookId").val(myBookId);
            });
        </script>

        
        <script>
            $(document).on("click", ".open-deleteDialog", function() {
                var myBook = $(this).data('id');
                $(".modal-body #cId").val(myBook);
            });
        </script>


</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know what line 153 is, but can you do a print_r of the object with error and tell us what you see? 
Generally that error means that instead of accessing it like this: $object[$index]['prop'], you have to access it like this: $object->prop

Comment: Yes I have added the print_r, but I can not see the reason for the uncaught error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $details->id instead of $details["id"], and so on

Comment: Thank you. How about in the case where we have more than one object adjacent to each other- example: 
$details["billing"]["first_name"].$details["billing"]["last_name"]."</td>

Comment: You can print_r($details->billing). 
If response is an array then:
$billing = $details->billing; $first_name = $billing['first_name'];
If response is an object then:
$first_name = $details->billing->first_name;